# Is `imap <s-bs> cmd` impossible in vim?

Tags: vim

Is it impossible to do a map with `<S-BS>` or `<C-BS>`?

I want to map it do delete a whole word. Something like:

```
" delete a word in insert mode
inoremap <s-bs> <Esc><Right>bdwi
```

Also tried:

```
" delete a word in insert mode using Ctrl + V then shift + <backspace>
inoremap ^? <Esc><Right>bdwi
```

Seems like backspace doesn't accepts Ctrl / Alt / Shift

Comment: @romainl I'm tring to make vim attractive more attractive do kate users. I guess they have to get used to it... `<c-w>`

Comment: I wasted three months trying to turn Vim into a textmate clone until I decided it wasn't worth it because Vim was so much more powerful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That depends; it should work in GVIM, but probably won't work in most terminals.

In insert or command-line mode, try typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>, followed by the key combination. If nothing happens / is inserted (or the same `<BS>` is inserted, ignoring the modifier keys), you cannot use that key combination.